# How to obtain non Italic theorem text

Tags: theorems, amsthm, xepersian

Please believe me this is not an Off Topic in TEX. Wait and see that I SEARCH the web and go deeply into questions for this but nothing found:

Can we equip ‎`AtBeginEnvironment` with two option **simultaneously**? I mean I want to have something like:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{‎‎\small}
```

which make whole examples a bit smaller in fonts, merged with the code `\emph` which make the whole body inside example environment unitalic.

What I did is:

```
‎‎\begin{example}‎‎
\emph{ John Smith}
\end{example}
```

to do so. Thanks for the hints.

---

Cosidering David's comment, I added my MWE as follows. It does not work as suggested. Maybe there is a defect in `xepersian` not working properly. See this plz:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{text={7in,9.5in},headheight=15pt}
\geometry{left=40.5mm,right=44.5mm,top=61mm,bottom=51mm}
\usepackage{mdframed}\usepackage[computeautoilg=off]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}\setdigitfont[Scale=1.3]{IRXLotus}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}[chapter]
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{‎‎\small\upshape}
‎\linespread{1.5}
‎\begin{document}
‎\begin{example}
با حل دستگاه، ‎$A=4$‎ و ‎$B=5$‏ و ‎لذا‎ داریم:
$$‎
\displaystyle\int f_2(x)~dx=\displaystyle\int \dfrac{4}{x-3}~dx-
\displaystyle\int\dfrac{5}{-2+x}~dx=
underbrace{4\ln|x-3|-5\ln|-2+x|}_{\ln~\left|\dfrac{(x-3)^4}{(x-2)^5}\right|}+C
$$‎
\qed
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

I hope every one can copy the codes and run it personally. If you do that, you will the Persian words are still italic, however, I did the suggested codes.

Comment: @campa Thanks. I does not change. It is still `small' (which is OK) and is still 'italic' (which is not of interest).

Comment: @campa Is it possible that some packages make bad effects such that your code does not work properly? Something like conflicting with each other?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks David for your hints. Thanks for the time. I'll do what you said in the next time and obey.

Comment: Your example gave a lot of errors due to unicode control characters and if I remove them I do not have the fonts, but you do not want to use AtBeginEnvironment here at all. _you_ have defined the `example` environment so you can define it not to be italic, see the amsthm package theoremstyle commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `amsthm` package provides several "theorem styles". While the default style, also known as the `plain` style, is programmed to typeset its body in italics, the `remark` and `definition` styles employ upright lettering. I therefore suggest that you insert the instruction

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
```

after loading `amsthm` and before issuing the instruction

```
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}[chapter]
```

(I'm afraid I can't run your MWE as two required fonts -- `XB Niloofar` and `IRXLotus` -- are not installed on my system. Sorry.)

Comment: Thanks I didn't have time to post a proper answer (after I changed the question:-)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your consideration. +1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks David for making the right title and for strong light on my question. You were the pioneer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks, David. You figured out what the OP's main issue was -- nothing to do with options being specified in an `\AtBeginEnvironment` directive...